# Appending a selected Range from Google Spreadsheet to a CSV file on Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-apps, google-sheets-api

I am trying to modify the following script, which saves a selected range to a new CSV file on Google drive.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial?hl=en

Please see: Section 3: Saving a selected Range to a CSV file

I would like to however append an existing CSV file with defined (named) range that I already created on Google Drive - I don't want to be prompted for its name. If and only if the CSV file not exist, then I want to create the new file.

This script should run via time-drive trigger (so that it runs automatically every minute and saves required range into csv file)

I would greatly appreciate your help how to modify this code.

Comment: So, the file name of the csv should be read from a named range in the spreadsheet? Or is it a preset name you'll be setting in your script?